# Integer part of $x^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, real-numbers, exponentiation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given a real number $x>1$ and a natural number $n$, what can we say about the integer part of $x^n$ in terms of $x$ and $n$?

For simplicity, let us assume $x<2$. For the first few values of $n$, $\left\lfloor x^n\right\rfloor =1$. But, once it crosses $1$, it starts growing quite rapidly. Is it possible to express $\left\lfloor x^n\right\rfloor$ in terms of $x$ and $n$? Or at least provide some bounds?

I was trying to think of it recursively. For a given $x>1$, let $I_n = \left\lfloor x^n\right\rfloor$ and $F_n = \left\{ x^n\right\}$ so that
$$I_{n+1} = \left\lfloor x(I_n+F_n)\right\rfloor$$
but this doesn't take me anywhere.

Any useful results will be appreciated. Some specific sequences are given in [OEIS A002379](https://oeis.org/A002379), [OEIS A064628](https://oeis.org/A064628) and [OEIS A091946](https://oeis.org/A091946).

**Please note that the question is to find $\lfloor x^n \rfloor$ given a $x$ and an $n$ without using the $\text{floor}$ operator**

Comment: If $x<2$ then $\lfloor x^n\rfloor<2^n$ and because $x\mapsto x^n$ is continuous you have from the intermediate value theorem that  $\lfloor x^n\rfloor$ can take all integer values between (and including) 1 and $2^n-1$ for $1<x<2$ .

Comment: Yes, but in my question, I am giving a specific $x$ and asking whether the integral part of $\lfloor x^n\rfloor$ can be expressed in terms of $x$ and $n$...

Comment: Answering your question in bold: raise $x$ to the $n$th power, then take the floor of that result. That is so obvious that I have to ask if the question in bold is what you really mean.

Comment: "Is it possible to express $\lfloor x^n\rfloor$ in terms of $x$ and $n$?" I don't understand because "$\lfloor x^n\rfloor$" is already expressing $\lfloor x^n\rfloor$ in terms of $x$ and $n$. Are you hoping to express it without using the floor operator?

Comment: The question is too vague see Mill's formula https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes

Comment: @2'59'2 the last note was added to prevent people from misunderstanding the question. But you are right, it would probably be better to add that I don't want the $\operatorname{floor}$ operator to be present.

Comment: @DesmosTutu I see your point, but as I said, I am happy to even receive any good bounds...

Comment: It is not clear to me what kind of answer you expect, or would be satisfied with. Even for $n=1$; what kind of expression would you want for $\lfloor x\rfloor$ in terms of $x$ and $n$?

Comment: @Servaes since $x<2$ was assumed, your answer would just be $1$, but I do see your point here...

Answer (score 0):

If $\lfloor x^n\rfloor<2$, then $x^n<2$, so $x<2^{\frac1n}$.

If $\lfloor x^n\rfloor<k$, then $x^n<k$, so $x<k^{\frac1n}$.

So for a given $k$, find $n$ such that

$k^{\frac1{n+1}}<x<k^{\frac1n}$

Comment: Again, the question is to find $\lfloor x^n \rfloor$ given a $x$ and an $n$...